# Power Bi Power Query best practice

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a large volume of CSV data that is imported and transformed, one of the columns has a range of values from 1-19, and is an age-group identifier (0-4,5-9,10-14,...,80-84,85+,age unknown).

My questions is

**"Is it best to add DAX code (likely a switch command) to make 1 = 0-4, 2 = 5-9,..., or is it better to do this in a different manner?"**

I know how to accomplish this in the import/transform data area, I'm looking for a better practice to consider.

**"If there is a better practice, can you please describe why the other method is deficient and the proposed better?"**

Answer (score 1):

PowerBI already has some in-built support that allows you to group multiple numeric values together called ["Grouping" and "Binning"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning). You can probably use that.

But w.r.t best practice is think you need to compare the three approaches and see what works best for you

1. **"Grouping" or "Binning"** - PowerBI takes care of it for you, but it may not be exactly what you're looking for.
2. **DAX** - this could impact the performance of the visual interactivity or loading
3. **Power Query** - This will simplify the performance with visuals, but will add time to make this transformation on every refresh.

What works for you will depend on what you're ready to accept.